# помогите понять очерёдность выполнения блоков в коде

Tags: java

имеем код

```
public class Test {
    {
        System.out.println("block 1");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("static 2");
    }

    Test() {
        System.out.println("constructor 3");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("block 4");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test1 = new Test();
        {
            System.out.println("main 5");
        }

    }
}
```

вывод :

```
static 2
block 1
block 4
constructor 3
main 5
```

если я правильно понял, статические блоки отрабатывают единожды  и в первую очередь на уровне класса...
тогда почему после `static 2` не отработал конструктор в статик методе?
а потом уже блок 1 и 4 и 5? Хотя в дебагере после вывода статик2 скакнул в конструктор , но не напечатал constructor 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Механизм очередности получается такой:

1. сначала загружаем класс (работает `ClassLoader`) при нем вызывается `static 2`
2. Далее начинается поиск точки входа, которой всегда является `static main()`, который является частью класса `Test`, соответственно срабатывают инициализирующие блоки класса `Test` (*Instance Initializer Block*) (`block 1/4`)
3. Далее `static main()` - срабатывает `constructor 3`
4. За ним уже `main 5`